# Merge files and insert it in BigQuery table

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a folder where I will get plenty of JSON files but every JSON has only 1 record.
Example of JSON file record :-

```
{"ID":"3193559","Title":"Una Familia de Diez - El secreto","Description":"Martina escucha que la Nena tiene novio y la amenaza con decirles a todos si no hace todo lo que le pida, pero despu\u00e9s la familia descubre su gran secreto.","Program":"Una Familia de Diez","Season":"1","Episode":"16","Source":"Televisa","Category":"Comedy","Syndicator":"CSv2","[CSv2] external_id":"UFDD100023004","[CSv2] pub_win_US_begin":"1657166400","[CSv2] pub_win_US_end":"1924923600","[CSv2] language":"es","[CSv2] title":"Una Familia de Diez - El secreto","[CSv2] descriptive_title":"El secreto","[CSv2] description":"Martina escucha que la Nena tiene novio y la amenaza con decirles a todos si no hace todo lo que le pida, pero despu\u00e9s la familia descubre su gran secreto.","[CSv2] supplier":"Televisa","[CSv2] categories":"Comedy","[CSv2] rating":"TV-14","[CSv2] subratings":"D,L","[CSv2] program_type":"SERIES","[CSv2] entity":"","[CSv2] exception_countries":"US ,\tUM ,PR ,\tMX ,\tAR ,\tCL ,\tCO ,\tPE ,\tEC ,\tCR ,\tSV ,\tHN ,\tBO ,\tPA ,\tDO ,\tNI ,\tPY ,\tVE ,\tUY ,\tGT","[CSv2] episode_type":"","TMS ID":"EP009112420015","external_id":"UFDD100023004","Content Type":"Entertainment","Release Year":"2007","sports_event_ID":""}
```

I am new to Python and GCP. Need help regarding this problem :-
How I can merge all the JSON files in Python and then insert it's data into stagging BigQuery table which I need to create in DAG and and then move those files in another folder, once inserted in BQ table. Also need to merge the stagging table data with final table based on id and once inserted, need to delete stagging table? So that whenever new files will come, it will repeat the whole process?

I have tried this in Python to read JSON file but it's not working :-

```
def map_keys(
    bucket_name, file_path, list_of_files
):  # pass the folder as an argument
    logging.info(f"bucket_name: {bucket_name}")
    logging.info(f"file_path: {file_path}")
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    logging.info(f"list_of_files from the DAG: {list_of_files}")
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(
        bucket_or_name=bucket_name, prefix=mcp_source_folder
    )
    blobs = [blob for blob in blobs if "json" in blob.name]
    logging.info(f"The process found {len(blobs)} files to insert")
    if not os.path.exists("unprocessed"):
        os.makedirs("unprocessed")
    if blobs:
        for blob in blobs:
            json_content = blob.download_as_string()
            mcp_data = json.loads(json_content)
            file_name = blob.name.split("/")[-1]
            logging.info(
                f"file to store: {file_name} with {len(mcp_data)} rows"
            )
            path_unprocessed_file = f"unprocessed/{file_name}"
            unprocessed_blob = bucket.blob(path_unprocessed_file)
            with open(path_unprocessed_file, "w") as unprocessed_file:
                for datum in mcp_data:
                    model_datum = McpModel.parse_obj(datum)
                    unprocessed_file.write(json.dumps(model_datum.dict()))
                    unprocessed_file.write("\n")
            unprocessed_blob.upload_from_filename(path_unprocessed_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you a solution and I hope it can help

You can use the following steps :

- Truncate your staging table
- Load all the input `Json` files from `GCS` to a `Bigquery` staging table via an `Airflow` operator
- Launch a `merge` query with `Airflow` between your staging and final table based `ID`
- Move input `Json` treaten files to another folder

Example :

```py
import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator


with airflow.DAG(
        "your_dag",
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

   truncate_staging_table = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='truncate_staging_table',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "TRUNCATE TABLE `project.dataset.staging_table`",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        location='EU'
    )

   load_json_to_staging_table = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_json_to_staging_table',
        bucket='your_bucket',
        source_objects='your_folder/*.json'],
     destination_project_dataset_table='your_project:your_dataset.your_staging_table',
        source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        compression='NONE',
        create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        autodetect=True
    )

   # In this example I used autodetect schema for files insertion 
   # on Bigquery, but you can also use a json schema for Bigquery with 
   # schema_fields

   merge_query = """
        MERGE `project.dataset.final_table` T
        USING `project.dataset.staging_table` S
        ON T.ID = S.ID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        
        UPDATE
        SET
            episode_type = S.episode_type,
            sports_event_ID = S.sports_event_ID
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ROW;
        """

   merge_final_table = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='merge_staging_to_final_table',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": merge_query,
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
        location='EU'
    )

   move_treaten_files = GCSToGCSOperator(
            task_id='move_treaten_files',
            source_bucket=your_source_bucket,
            source_object='source_folder/*',
            destination_bucket=your_dest_bucket,
            destination_object='dest_folder/',
            move_object=True
        )

   truncate_staging_table >> load_json_to_staging_table >> merge_final_table >> move_treaten_files
```

I written an article on `Medium` to give a complete use case on data deduplication with `Bigquery` batch pipeline and `Airflow` DAG :

[Remove duplicates in Bigquery batch pipeline with Airflow and Dataflow](https://medium.com/google-cloud/remove-duplicates-in-bigquery-batch-pipeline-with-airflow-and-dataflow-2e7da5772c4d)

This article shows many ways to use `Bigquery` `merge` query.

Comment: TRUNCATE is not working . File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_mcp_test_new.py", line 17
    "query": TRUNCATE TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_data_mcp.staging_table`,
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @MazlumTosun

Comment: I proposed a correction on the `truncate` query. Quote was missing. You have then to adapt this code to match with your tables and dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you already 1 json on 1 line your are lucky. So, you have 2 solutions

- Either you use the BigQuery load job feature with a wildcard to select all the files (with a common prefix in Cloud Storage for instance (also named "directory" but directories don't exist)
- Or take inspiration from one of [my articles](https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886) to query Cloud Storage API, loop over the object and use the compose feature to merge all the file in one. Then, call the BigQuery load job feature on this single job.

Comment: Can you share an example? I am new to these, so leaning these things

Comment: Example of what? Integration with wildcard of Cloud Workflows?

Comment: Example of what? Integration with wildcard of Cloud Workflows?